# Inputs with date or time types do not work in iOS when running web app in standalone mode

Tags: forms, webview, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari

When using `<input type="date" />` or `<input type="time" />`, for an app in standalone mode added via "Add to Home screen", those elements will not open the usual popover content allowing the user to select date or time. Even though the same works as expected when opened regularly within Safari. In standalone mode they will instead just fill the current date and current time when clicked, allowing no further interaction.

I guess my questions are:

1. Is this a (known) bug in iOS/Safari?
2. Does it have a *hacky* workaround, other than using a custom datetimepicker library?